# Dynamic method in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a method in python, which accepts 1-n number of parameters, calls the same method on each and returns the result. For example;

(Note this is pseudo code, I'm just typing these methods/syntax on the fly - new to python )

```
def get_pid(*params):
    pidlist = []
    for param in params:
        pidlist.add(os.getpid(param))
    return pidlist
```

Ideally I would like to do something like

```
x, y = get_pid("process1", "process2")
```

Where I can add as many parameters as I want - and the method to be as 'pythonic' and compact as possible. I think there may be a better way than looping over the parameters and appending to a list?

Any suggestions/tips?

Comment: Your code already *almost* works as written, it is `pidlist.append()`, not `.add()`.

Comment: I come from a java background - I'm trying to get into the "python" way of thinking. Is there any way to improve on this code? I'd imagine the 4 lines can probably be changed to 1/2 lines

Comment: @Alan: that's true, you can make it more compact (via a listcomp or map or something) but please don't get in the habit of associating "pythonic" and "short".  "Pythonic" doesn't mean "golfed", it means something more like "clear and straightforward".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code *already works*. Your function accepts 0 or more arguments, and returns the results for each function call. There is but a minor mistake in it; you should use `list.append()`; there is no `list.add()` method.

You could use a list comprehension here to do the same work in one line:

```
def get_pid(*params):
    return [os.getpid(param) for param in params]
```

You could just inline this; make it a generator expression perhaps:

```
x, y = (os.getpid(param) for param in ("process1", "process2"))
```

You could also use the `map()` function for this:

```
x, y = map(os.getpid, ("process1", "process2"))
```

Comment: By the way, `set` has the `set.add()` method :)

Comment: @KevinGuan: sure, but that is neither here nor there when using a list. There are other Python objects that have `.add` methods too, but those are also not lists. :-P

Answer (score 4):

You can use yield to create a generator:

```
def get_pid(*params):
    for param in params:
        yield os.getpid(param)

x, y = get_pid("process1", "process2")
print(x, y)
```